# Implementing ADT prosthetics in scala - why the compiler doesn't want my implicit?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit, algebraic-data-types

I want to propagate type alternatives to first-rate types. I want to be able to write:

```
val union :Int || String = 1
```

So far I have come up with this:

```
object ADT {

sealed abstract class ||[+A, +B] {
    def value :Any

    protected[ADT] def asLeft :Option[A]
    protected[ADT] def asRight :Option[B]

    override def equals(o :Any) = o match {
        case alt: ||[_,_] => (alt eq this) || alt.value == value
        case _ => value == o
    }

}

object || {
    /** Magical conversions */
    implicit def generalize[T, X](value :X)(implicit ev :SuperType[T, X]) :T = ev.cast(value)


    trait SuperType[+X, -Y] {
        protected[ADT] def cast(value :Y) :X
    }
    //You can skip reading the rest at first, as it probably isn't the problem
    object SuperType {
        implicit def identity[X, Y](implicit ev : Y<:<X) = //:SuperType[X, Y] =
            new DirectSuperType[X, Y]

        implicit def leftComponent[A, B, Y](implicit ev :SuperTypeAlternative[A, Y]) :SuperTypeAlternative[A || B, Y] =
            new LeftSuperTypeAlternative[A, B, Y](ev)

        implicit def rightComponent[A, B, Y](implicit ev :SuperTypeAlternative[B, Y]) :SuperTypeAlternative[A || B, Y] =
            new RightSuperTypeAlternative[A, B, Y](ev)

        implicit def forall[X, A, B](implicit ev1 :SuperType[X, A], ev2 :SuperType[X, B]) :SuperType[X, A || B] =
            new ForAll[X, A, B](ev1, ev2)

        trait SuperTypeAlternative[+X, -Y] extends SuperType[X, Y]

        class DirectSuperType[+X, -Y](implicit ev : Y<:<X) extends SuperTypeAlternative[X, Y] {
            override def cast(value: Y): X = value
        }


        private[this] class LeftSuperTypeAlternative[+A, +B, Y](sup :SuperType[A, Y]) extends SuperTypeAlternative[A|| B, Y] {
            override protected[ADT] def cast(value: Y): A || B = new LeftVariant(sup.cast(value))    
        }
        private[this] class RightSuperTypeAlternative[+A, +B, Y](sup :SuperType[B, Y]) extends SuperTypeAlternative[A || B, Y] {
            override protected[ADT] def cast(value: Y): A || B = new RightVariant(sup.cast(value))
        }

        private class ForAll[+X, -A, -B](rest :SuperType[X, A], last :SuperType[X, B]) extends SuperType[X, A || B] {
            override protected[ADT] def cast(value: A || B): X = value match {
                case LeftVariant(x) => rest.cast(x)
                case RightVariant(x) => last.cast(x)
            }
        }
    }


    private final case class LeftVariant[+A](left :A) extends ||[A, Nothing] {
        override protected[ADT] def asLeft: Option[A] = Some(left)
        override protected[ADT] def asRight: Option[Nothing] = None

        override def value: Any = left match {
            case adt : ||[_,_] => adt.value
            case x => x
        }
    }
    private final case class RightVariant[+B](right :B) extends ||[Nothing, B] {
        override protected[ADT] def asLeft: Option[Nothing] = None
        override protected[ADT] def asRight: Option[B] = Some(right)

        override def value: Any = right match {
            case adt : ||[_,_] => adt.value
            case x => x
        }

    }

}

def main(args :Array[String]) {
    import ||.SuperType
    implicitly[SuperType[Int || String, Int]]
    val union :Int || String = ||.generalize(1)
}

}//ADT
```

When compiled with scala 2.10 and -Xlog-implicits, I get:

```
Information:(51, 5) conforms is not a valid implicit value for <:<[Y,X] because:
    hasMatchingSymbol reported error: type mismatch;
    found   : <:<[Y,Y]
    required: <:<[Y,X]
            new DirectSuperType[X, Y]
            ^
Information:(120, 32) ADT.this.||.generalize is not a valid implicit value for Int =>   com.citi.gumshoe.util.ADT.||[Int,String] because:
    incompatible: (value: Int)(implicit ev:   com.citi.gumshoe.util.ADT.||.SuperType[T,Int])T does not match expected type Int =>  com.citi.gumshoe.util.ADT.||[Int,String]
    val union :Int || String = 1
                                 ^
Information:(120, 32) ADT.this.||.generalize is not a valid implicit value for (=> Int) => com.citi.gumshoe.util.ADT.||[Int,String] because:
   incompatible: (value: Int)(implicit ev:  com.citi.gumshoe.util.ADT.||.SuperType[T,Int])T does not match expected type (=> Int) =>  com.citi.gumshoe.util.ADT.||[Int,String]
        val union :Int || String = 1
                                 ^
Error:(120, 32) type mismatch;
    found   : Int
    required: com.citi.gumshoe.util.ADT.||[Int,String]
    val union :Int || String = 1
```

But this line works:

```
val union :Int || String = ||.generalize(1)
```

SuperType implicit is seen, as this line compiles:

```
val sup = implicitly[SuperType[Int || String, Int]                                   ^
```

I can make it work by removing implicit from generalize introducing this implicit:

```
implicit def gen[X, Y](x :X) :X || Y = ||.generalize(x)
```

But only if this declaration is outside of `object ||`. I feel like I have no idea what's happening...

Comment: You may want to look at scalaz.\/ which implements a union type

Comment: Could you post something that compiles? modulo your problem.

Comment: Added encapsulating object, so the whole file compiles.

Answer (score 0):

After some googling and reading up on scala type system it seems that it just won't work - scala won't use an implicit conversion with implicit parameters if its return type is not bound by explict parameter list, due dark magic that happens in the compiler. I'll have to settle for something like this:

```
implicit class Generalization[T](val something :T) extends AnyVal {
    def widen[X](implicit ev: X SuperType T) = ev.cast(value)
}

val union :Int || String = 1.widen
```

Or has anybody a more clever idea?

Answer (score 0):

Move your implicit + the extra def gen... to the end of || object.
It compiles on 2.10.

There is some weirdness about visibility of types and how scala compiles implicts.

Comment: Well, making it compile using def gen is not much, I wanted full conversion between all union types where conformance can be statically proved...